# How to terminate an ssh command that was ran from a remote host?

Tags: linux, ssh, server, process, pid

I ran an ssh command doing the following: `ssh user@remote "my command &"`. Now the process seems to be running in the background, but I cannot find it, and I want to end it. I've used netstat, but cannot find the process.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest some methods

```
sudo killall ssh
```

It may not be the best method to use this method, it is better to filter first and then close it

or

```
ps -o pid,cmd | grep ssh

kill -QUIT (pid)
```

To stop a program, send the QUIT signal.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you expect it to run in the background?  Thats what the `&` does.  You can use `ps af` to show all of the processes running under your username.  You can then `kill` it by PID.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody. I found the process doing `ps aux`. For some reason, the port that it was using wasn't being display in netstat.